# Javascript datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using the Javascript datatables plugin: https://datatables.net
Is it possible to specify the column type when exporting data to excel? I want to specify a certain column to be a time format in the final excel document. I have looked at the documentation: https://datatables.net/manual/index but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is a function called [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) which does exactly this.

Buttons has two different methods that can be used to format the data exported differently from the data that is shown in the table: orthogonal options as shown in this example and formatting functions. They both achieve basically the same thing in different ways: namely modification of the output data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: '../../../../examples/ajax/data/objects.txt',
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'position' },
            { data: 'office' },
            { data: 'extn' },
            { data: 'start_date' },
            { data: 'salary', render: function (data, type, row) {
                return type === 'export' ?
                    data.replace( /[$,]/g, '' ) :
                    data;
            } }
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Referred from https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-orthogonal.html